# In JsRender Template, How to set css of dom element if Array to be iterated contains specifics String values?

Tags: jsrender

In JsRender Template,
I have a td that contains iterated elements of array statusShortList

```
<td style="width:100px;" class="primary-bg">
{{for statusShortList}}{{>#data}}{{if #index < #parent.data.length - 1}}-{{/if}}{{/for}}
</td>
```

How can I set the td text color if array statusShortList contains String "wappr" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way:

Provide a helper, such as:

```
var helpers = {
  inArr: function(str, arr) {
    return $.inArray(str, arr) > -1;
  }
};

var html = tmpl.render(data, helpers);
```

and use it in your template like this:

```
<td style="width:100px; color:{{:~inArr('wappr', statusShortList) ? 'red' : 'black'}}" class="primary-bg">
  ...
```

Comment: Your to the point answer made it clear that _helpers_ is an object that can contain multiple callback-helpers. That is proving useful ! Thank you !

Comment: Yes, multiple helpers can be passed in like that, or you can register helpers using $.views.helpers(...). See http://www.jsviews.com/#helpers. They can be functions, values, objects, any type you want...